# Showing startup RuntimeException on error page in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

When my Tomcat app starts, it needs to check some configuration files for errors. If it finds an error, I want it to display the cause of the error in an error page.

It's straight forward to catch an exception in a servlet or jsp once the app is deployed and display the stacktrace or whatever, but how can I display a RuntimeException that has occurred while the app is starting up?

catalina.out:

```
17-Feb-2022 06:17:02.241 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] beans.ConnectionMap.<init> e = beans.PinClashException: Valve connection: 6 is already allocated to pin GPIO 31 but MistingUnit Mist3 is set to use the same pin in connectionMapMisters.txt.Compare /home/pi/irrigation/connectionMapMisters.txt with /home/pi/irrigation/connectionMap.txt to fix the problem
17-Feb-2022 06:17:02.709 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/GH2.war] has finished in [5,182] ms
```

web.xml:

```
<error-page>
        <exception-type>beans.PinClashException</exception-type>
        <location>/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.RuntimeException</exception-type>
        <location>/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

Comment: Implement a `ServletContextListener` - In the `contextInitialized` method check you configuration files and log the errors to a DB or flat file.

Comment: Thanks, good plan. I put a log line into contextInitialised and that gets called sooner than I expected, so I can post the errors via that. Cheers.